# Multipolygon postgis layer exposed via geoserver is empty at certain zoom levels

Tags: postgis, geoserver

I have the following issue:

There is a postgis table that contains a geometry column of type multipolygon (epsg is 4326, if it's relevant).

This layer is exposed via geoserver. When I preview this layer with openlayers, everyting is fine starting at scale of 1 : 35M. 
However, when I zoom out, objects just dissapear. I had the style set to `Point`, so polygons being too small should not be the issue.

Currently I have a `FeatureTypeStyle` which uses `PointSymbolizer` with `<MinScaleDenominator>10000000</MinScaleDenominator>` and `PolygonSymbolizer` with `<MaxScaleDenominator>10000000</MaxScaleDenominator>`, and I've tried using only `PointSymbolizer` with the same result.

Geoserver version is 2.8.0.

What might be the problem here?

Comment: do you have Support on the fly geometry simplification turned on for the store?

Comment: @iant wow, that was fast. I actually did. removing it solved the issue. thanks for the prompt reply!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are still some issues with the PostGIS on the fly simplification sometimes. So the quick answer is to turn it off for now and see if the issue goes away.

For bonus marks if you can isolate the Polygon(s) that cause the issue and raise a bug report with them attached so it gets fixed.

Comment: The issues are on the postgis side, it seems that a new function was added to the latest version of postgis that we could use instead of st_simplify, that should not have this problem